# Does the V8 javascript engine compile all javascript to machine language?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, v8

Does the V8 engine that is used in Chrome and Node.js compile the entire code to machine language once or it compiles the next context to be executed every time for each context that is added to the call stack ?

Comment: @trincot this question is a _very_ poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/839601). Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/291230/how-does-chrome-v8-work-and-why-was-javascript-not-jit-compiled-in-the-first-pl

Comment: @gnat It doesn't sound like tech support question at all.   It's asking for specifics on a generally available library's behavior which can be relevant for programming endeavors.    It's not a great question, but it's not customer support by any stretch.

Comment: Think carefully about the meaning of "JIT" (just in time) compiler.

Answer (score 1):

V8 will likely compile some of your code to machine language and likely not compile all of it to machine language.

The exact representation for any piece of code depends on many factors, including the ever-changing optimization behaviors in the library.  None of it is guaranteed and shouldn't be treated as such, even if it behaves a certain way right now.